# Why do I get no output for my program

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I use `socket` to create a tcp connection, and check if a server port of 443 is open.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

remoteServer    = raw_input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

print "-" * 60
print "Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP
print "-" * 60

t1 = datetime.now()

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, 443))
    if result == 0:
        print "Port {443}: Open"
    else:
        print "Port {443}: Close"
    sock.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "You pressed Ctrl+C"
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print "Couldn't connect to server"
    sys.exit()

t2 = datetime.now()
total =  t2 - t1
print 'Scanning Completed in: ', total
```

Sometimes I got output with `open` or `close`, but sometime I got no output. For example, I input `64.233.160.2` or `64.233.160.3`, no `open` or `close` output. what's wrong with me?

Comment: did you try putting everything in a try and have a general except to see whats wrong?

Comment: @JohnRuddell there is no wrong. Just no output, and program seems can't stop running only when you press ctrl+c

Comment: if you try to `telnet` such IPs, you get `Trying 64.233.160.3...` hanging indefinitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the machine you're trying to connect to is neither accepting nor actively refusing connections. Try setting a timeout for your connection (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

The fact that your program is not exiting until you press `Ctrl-C` suggests that the `socket.connect` call is blocking.

Comment: that is exactly what is going on, see my comment above